# Get height of div element in angularjs and set it to another element's attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is it possible to get the height of element with angularjs and put it onto attribute of another div?

I have a bootstrap webpage which has affix sidebar and in order for it to correctly stop before web page footer I have to specify footer's height in attribute of affix.
Currently I'm doing this manually.

It mostly looks something like this:

View 1:

```
<div class="affix-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-bottom="300">
...
</div>
```

Layout (main) view:

```
...
<div id="footer">
...
</div>
```

The *300* is the manually entered height of footer, I would like to change View 1 to something like this (pseudocode):

```
<div class="affix-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-bottom="{{#footer.height()}}">
...
</div>
```

Is this possible? If it's not that easy in angularjs, what I could use to get that functionality without using separate javascript if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a variable on the angular scope to a default value; fill it up once it becomes available.

```
$scope.height = 0;

$scope.updateHeight = function(){
  $scope.height = document.querySelector("#wantedDiv").clientHeight;
  console.log("height is now: "+$scope.height);
  if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
};
window.onload= $scope.updateHeight;
```

Use in your html:

```
<div class="affix-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-bottom="{{height}}">
...
</div>
```

Also, you could assign this to any other event you want to.

```
window.onresize= $scope.updateHeight;
```

Comment: If I for example update this variable in window.onresize event will this attribute update automatically?